# uibutton animation within timeframe

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton

i have a button.what I need to do is when i click on the button once it will blink red and white.but when I click the button twice within two seconds it will turn red until the action done.I am new to ios programming so confused.thanks in advance.

Comment: put a view above button through code and animate it

Comment: Its simple, You can keep a flag for when last button was clicked if its whithin two second make it turn into red and set it to normal when action is done !! :)

Answer (score 1):

change your button position which one you wants to be make animation like top.bottom,left,right.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        button.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 0, 0);
    }];
```

Or

```
[UIView transitionWithView:button
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:NULL
                completion:NULL];
```

Alternatively:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.duration = 0.5;
[button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,
You can keep a flag for when last button was clicked if its whithin two second make it turn into red and set it to normal when action is done !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of UIButton you should use UIView with 2 UITapGestureRecognizers? One of them would have numberOfTapsRequired = 2, the other one would have numberOfTapsRequired = 1. Use method requiresGestureRecognizerToFail to make sure that you won't have them both calling their target methods. Then you can add any logic you want to the tap handling,  and use the timer

```
btn.enabled = NO;
if (btn.tag == 0) {

// change to pause button
// start process

btn.tag = 1;
}
else if (btn.tag == 1) {

// change to play button
// stop process

btn.tag = 0;
}
btn.enabled = YES;
```